# Sudden infinite loop above certain input argument?

Tags: java, infinite-loop, integer-overflow

While learning Java I'm redoing some of the Project Euler problems.
This is about Problem 14 - Longest Collatz sequence: https://projecteuler.net/problem=14

My programm runs just fine for a lower `CEILING` like 1000, but when executed like posted it loops infinitely, I think? What goes wrong here?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tempMax = 0;
        final int CEILING = 1_000_000;

        for (int j = 1; j < CEILING; ++j) {
            tempMax = Math.max(tempMax, collatzLength(j));
        }
        System.out.println(tempMax);
    }

    static int collatzLength(int n) { //computes length of collatz-sequence starting with n
            int temp = n;

            for (int length = 1; ; ++length) {
                if (temp == 1) 
                    return length;
                else if (temp % 2 == 0)
                    temp /= 2;
                else
                    temp = temp * 3 + 1;
            }
    }
}
```

Calling `System.out.println(collatzLength(1000000));` seperately works just fine so I think we can rule an error here out.

Comment: Are you sure it's just not taking a really long time?

Comment: If `n == 0`, which can happen when `temp` somehow overflows to `-1`,  `collatzLenght` will never terminate. You might want to rule out that special case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `long` instead of `int`. The `int` overflows while doing your calculations in `collatzLength` and that causes the infinite loop. From the problem description:

> NOTE: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one million.

**The number causing the problem: 113383**

The `long` version gives a result, which is still incorrect because you are printing the length of the longest chain, but you need the number which produces the longest chain.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int tempMax = 0;
    final int CEILING = 1_000_000;

    for (int j = 1; j < CEILING; ++j)
    {
        tempMax = Math.max(tempMax, collatzLength(j));
    }
    System.out.println(tempMax);
}

static int collatzLength(long n)
{
    long temp = n;

    for (int length = 1;; ++length)
    {
        if (temp == 1)
            return length;
        else if (temp % 2 == 0)
            temp /= 2;
        else
            temp = temp * 3 + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, look at using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to speed up the calculation significantly.